# How to distribute memory among the Java ThreadPoolExecutor tasks?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, threadpoolexecutor

I have a list of tasks. Each task consumes different amount of memory. 
I can predict memory consumption for particular task very roughly, so I can't rely on such predictions.

For instance:

- Tasks consumes from 200m to 1g of RAM, but 450m avg.
- Max memory is 2G (-Xmx2g)
- And number of available threads is 4.

So if I'll just submit them all, I have OutOfMemmoryException with almost 100% chance.
If I'll use only 2 or 1 thread, I loose performance.

I'm going to check available free memory inside runnable task during execution, terminate it if there is not enough memory, and execute them later with smaller amount of threads. But there is possible race condition when all four tasks detects low memory level at the same time, and terminate them-selfs. So I need some kind of supervisor which will evict tasks one by one.

Anyway this solution doesn't seems elegant, so is there best practices for such case, maybe some way to control tasks submission rate or anything else?

Comment: I don't know what work your threads are doing, but if you're dealing with some collection of data, can't you just lazily stream the collection and process? That way, you won't come across OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: Every task actually make some spatial stuff (like point-in-polygon location, neighbor point searching and so on). And most of memory used for spatial indexes. I've already done some kind of streaming, but still I have to store some data in RAM.

Comment: Take a look at [Flyweight Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern). Maybe you can minimise the objects in your space by using it.

Comment: If there's too much data still, maybe you can serialise portions of data in files, and deserialise them again when their need arises. That way, you can use the hard drive space as a virtual RAM.

Comment: There are concurrent data structures available in Java libraries. So IF you are having multiple copies of the same data which various threads work upon, then you can use the concurrent structures and the threads can work concurrently on the same structure. It can save space if you're having local copies of the data.

Comment: And while working with large data, you have to accept that processing it will take some time. To prevent OutOfMemoryException, you can sequentially run tasks, or half the tasks at a time, and once they are done, run the other half of tasks. This way they'll use the garbage collected memory, and you won't run out of memory.

Comment: I've already made data serialization, and now I want to do some work with stored portions of data in parallel way. The question is not about how to save memory, but how to distribute memory between parallel executed tasks.